# When is a port considered being used?

Tags: networking, process, socket, administration

I am getting port in use cannot bind on process restarts. I am trying to find out when a port is considered being used?

Is it only when in LISTEN mode?
Can it also be if a connection is open to the port in TIME_WAIT state (or any other state in the TCP [finite state machine](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm))?

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30099/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:9160          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30099/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:58263         192.168.1.2:9042          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:58262         192.168.1.2:9042          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   :::*                        LISTEN      30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57191  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57190  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:10.176.70.226:37105  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:42562      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7199       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57190  ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ESTABLISHED 30138/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57198  ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ESTABLISHED 30138/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:10.176.70.226:37106  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57197  ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ESTABLISHED 30138/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57191  ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ESTABLISHED 30138/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57198  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.2:9042   ::ffff:192.168.1.2:57197  ESTABLISHED 30099/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:42567      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7199       TIME_WAIT   -
```

The process in question is a Java process which exposes JMX port. And there are a few monitoring agents that send request to that port to get information. I want to make sure that when the restart happens (after stop and before start) the ports are free so it won't run into the port bind issue. If a pending TIME_WAIT connection on that port is considered for the port being used, then I will add waits in between stop and start for those TIME_WAIT states to get cleaned up before the process starts. Unless there is another preferred option.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A port is considered "in use" whenever there are any sockets bound to it. They don't have to be in LISTEN state, just bound. Therefore the TIME_WAIT sockets that you see do count.

It gets a little bit more complicated if any sockets are bound to addresses *and* ports. Different sockets are allowed to be bound to the same port if they're bound to different addresses. But if there is any socket bound to the wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`, shown by `netstat` as `*`) for that port, it prevents other sockets from binding to *any* address and that same port.

Normally, most software that uses listening sockets sets the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option on those sockets. This option relaxes the rules. With the option set, only a bound *and* listening socket prevents another socket from binding to the same address. This means that any lingering `TIME_WAIT` and other sockets will not prevent the software from restarting and rebinding immediately to the same port.

Your Java program is most likely not setting `SO_REUSEADDR` on its socket, but it should.

Comment: Where can I read more about this? Thanks

Comment: Try the [socket manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) for quick reference info. The venerable textbook for this information is [TCP/IP illustrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Illustrated). I'm probably dating myself by recommending that, there might be something good that's more recent, but then again you can't go wrong with Stevens.

Comment: A socket is identified by IP address and port number.

Comment: @vonbrand, what do you mean by that? A socket is not really "identified" by that since not all sockets are necessarily bound.